# What is the difference between ARINC 429 labels 025 and 102 for Selected Altitude?

Tags: avionics

What is the difference between ARINC 429 labels 025 and 102 for Selected Altitude?

Answer (score 2):

According to A429, the difference is the type of data coding. Label 025 is BCD. Label 102 is BNR.

Label 025 by being a Binary Coded Decimal codes each character of the altitude value in binary. With a range of 0 to 50000 feet, the first digit uses 3 bits and the remaining use 4 bits each for total of 19 data bits.

Label 102 is a Binary number. The range is 0 to 65535. There are 16 data bits (2^16 = 65536).

Both are transmitted. Receivers will use the version most appropriate for the application.  BCD is normally used for display. BNR is normally used in computations.